# jQuery insertAfter not working

Tags: jquery, insertafter

I have a set of buttons:

```
  <div id="button">
      <button id="show_link_group">Show Links</button>
      <button id="show_contact_group">Show Contacts</button>
      <button id="show_update_group">Show Updates</button>
      <button id="show_activity_group">Show Action Items</button>
  </div>
```

And I am trying to insert my this div after it:

```
<div id="link_group">

      <p1>adsfadsf</p1>
</div>
```

It is supposed to insert after I click a button with id="show_link_group":

```
$('#show_link_group').click(function() {
  $("<div id='link_group'").after('<div id="button"></div>');
});
```

When I click it, it doesn't do anything. I followed this documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/

What am I doing wrong??

thanks!

Comment: Your selector is _wrong_, and you are using the `after` method not the `insertAfter`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a selector to specify where to insert, not an HTML string.

```
$("<div id='link_group'><p1>asdfasdf</p1></div>").insertAfter("#button");
```

if the `link_group` DIV is already in the DOM, you can do:

```
$("#link_group").insertAfter("#button");
```

This will move it from its current location to after the button.

Comment: Do we have `p1` element?

Comment: No, but the OP apparently doesn't care, that's what he wants to insert.

Comment: @barmar - I don't have a p1 element in my link_group. My link_group has a bunch of tables, paragraphs, and lists. I want to insert everything in my link_group under my #button. please advise.

Comment: You have `<p1>` in the question.

Comment: that was just a placeholder.. i actually have a bunch of tables and other elements in there... Basically I want to place EVERYTHING in link_group under #button @Barmar

Comment: So replace that placeholder with whatever should actually be there.

Answer (score 1):

You have the .after() method backwards. You need to first tell it, "after what element do I want to insert it." Then you tell it the content to insert after that element.

You have this:

```
$('#show_link_group').click(function() {
  $("<div id='link_group'").after('<div id="button"></div>');
});
```

You want this:

```
var content = "my content";
$('#show_link_group').click(function() {
   $("#button").after(content);
});
```

Here is a jsbin with your solution. http://jsbin.com/qaxan/1/edit

Comment: The question is about `insertAfter`, not `after`. His code used the wrong one.

Comment: You are correct. I went with the use of .after() since that is what was in the user's code. According to the insertAfter() documentation, they both perform the same task, "The major difference is in the syntax-specifically, in the placement of the content and target." The jsbin I added shows both in use.